# SSH key stopped working, still works on other servers

Tags: ssh, public-key, file-permissions

I've got about a dozen servers that I log into via an authorised ssh key, and up until today it was working fine. Today, one of those servers refuses to accept my key - it accepts a root key and my passphrase, just not my key. Nothing has changed in the ssh configs, and the key is still in my `authorized_keys`. Any idea why it's stopped working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.ssh directory chmod 700`?
- `.ssh/authorized_keys chmod 600`?

owned by you?

If the server sshd_config wasn't changed and the other keys work, I would suspect something happened to the directory or permissions that contain your key.

Comment: .ssh is 0700, authorized_keys is 0600. Both owned by me.

Comment: key matches?  anything in the auth logs?

Comment: `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/<username>`. Currently 0770.

Comment: I believe the group writeable may be what caused it to decline.  Try chmod 750 and ls -ald /home/username to make sure the uid/gid exist.

Comment: Aha! Fixed! Excellent. Group writable was it.